# Hash of seen DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, dom, hash, mutation-observers

I'd like to attach a `MutationObserver` to the DOM so I can see what changes. Easy.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    processNode(mutation.target);
  });
});

var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true
};
observer.observe(document.body, config);
```

The problem is in `processNode` I want to edit the nodes, which triggers the `MutationObserver` which calls `processNode` again which double edits the node, which I don't want.

So how can I make a hash to keep track of what I've already seen? Things I've tried:

1. WeakMap

Doesn't work because all nodes are serialized to strings before insertion. So my keys become `[object Text]`. **Edit**: I was doing `seenMap[node] = true` instead of `seenMap.set(node, true)`. The latter works as a solution to my problem.

2. Storing attribute on the node

I don't want to cause collisions with anything else running on the page (I'm writing a Chrome Extension).

3. Using an array of seen DOM Nodes

I'm not too excited about a linear search for each DOM change.

Comment: How about keeping a `global-flag` and manipulate things based on its state(`true/false`) ?

Comment: I do want to process newly added nodes when they are added by something other than my extension, so a simple true/false for the whole app won't work.

Comment: My suggestion was, when you manipulate things in `processNode`, by using a _simple flag_, you can prevent invoking `processNode`

Comment: `So my keys become [object Text]` Then you are using the WeakMap wrong. Did you use `.set` and `.get` or did you try to do `wkMap[node] = foo`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth wow, thanks. I was doing it wrong. I'm a little sad it responds to `[]` but does the wrong thing instead of yelling at me.

Comment: Yup, it's still an object like most things, so you can add properties to it all you want using normal property assignment, but `get` and `set` are the methods for storing and retrieving data into the actual map.

Comment: In modern browsers (Chrome 38+, Firefox 36+) it's possible to use [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) as a unique property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with adding properties to Node Objects. JQuery does this all the time and it's very common in browser extensions. Also, I don't mean Element attributes like `<img data-foo="bar"/>`. I mean adding properties to the Node Objects in JS, e.g.

```
document.body.MY_WEIRD_PROP_348u9erhhhhh0asdf_IN_USE = 1
```

Obviously, you'd want it to be obscure to fully avoid collisions. If you can think of an instance where this would interfere with another script, please enlighten me.